# Python program that reads pnm files

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I need to create a program that reads pnm files using the mcsp.wartburg.edu graphics.py library found [here](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node1.html). So far this is what I have:

```
from graphics import *

#Function chunks the list into groups of n, for example,
#List = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
#with chucker lists becomes ['2', '3', '4'] and ['5','6','7'] and so on

def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in xrange(0, len(seq), size))

def main():

fText =open("rainbowGS1.pnm", "r")
data = fText.readlines()
fText.close()

for ch in chunker(data[3:], 3):
    print ch
```

I'm not sure how to take these groups and set their RGB values using the setPixel(x, y, color) function found [here](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node12.html), and the color=color_rgb(255, 0, 0) function. I can't use color_rgb(ch) because this function accepts 3 arguments. By using color_rgb(ch) one argument is being passed. Help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you breaking into groups of length 3 because those 3 represent R-G-B respectively?

Comment: Try ch[0], ch[1], ch[2], perhaps with an ord() for each.  I'm not really sure how graphics.py is helping you though; you don't seem to be using it.  Note that there are two kinds of pnm files: binary and text.  Your code appears to be assuming text format.  I've got an example of -writing- a ppm (which is a color portable pixmap, where pnm can be color, grayscale or black&white) here: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/circle/trunk/circle .  Don't forget that the file starts with format, dimensions and colors, before getting into the individual color triples.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that each ch has a length of 3 but when I use the color_rgb function it recognizes ch as one argument. I need to use color_rgb to convert the RGB values to hexadecimal and then set the pixels to that color.

Comment: @dstromberg it's a P2 Portable graymap ASCII file. By the way, thanks for the example I'll look into it.

Comment: @user1789663: [P2 is grayscale](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html). Why do you need rgb?

Comment: Here's [`netpbmfile.py`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/netpbmfile.py.html) that works with `numpy` arrays and plot data using `matplotlib`. It understands several pnm formats (`P1-P7`, `P7 332`)